# How to use defined?(super) with define_method

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming

When I use `define_method` from within a block passed to an iterator, for some reason `defined?(super)` never evaluates to `true`.

See the example below. Note that `super(value)` *is* a valid call, even though `defined?` thinks otherwise.

```
class A
  def message=(val)
    puts 'A says ' + val
  end
end

class B < A
  ['message', 'warning'].each do |method|
    define_method(method + '=') do |val|
      puts 'B says ' + val
      super(val) if defined?(super)
    end
  end
end

a = A.new
a.message = 'hello!' # A says hello!
b = B.new
b.message = 'hello!' # B says hello!

############################################

class B < A
  ['message', 'warning'].each do |method|
    define_method(method + '=') do |val|
      puts 'B says ' + val
      super(val) rescue nil
    end
  end
end

b = B.new
b.message = 'hello!' # B says hello! A says hello!
```

Comment: I can’t reproduce this, using your first example half it calls `A#message` when `B#message` is called. What version of Ruby?

Comment: ruby 1.9.3p448 (2013-06-27 revision 41675) [x86_64-darwin12.4.0]

Comment: Indeed, this behavior doesn't seem to exist in `ruby 2.1.0p0 (2013-12-25 revision 44422) [x86_64-darwin12.0]`.

Comment: I can't reproduce this in ruby 2.0.0p353

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is [a bug](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/6644) in Ruby 1.9.3 that was fixed in 2.0.0-p0 but never backported to 1.9.3. The reported bug isn’t *exactly* the same, but [its fix](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/projects/ruby-trunk/repository/revisions/36369/diff/insns.def) is likely what solved this.

Likely this arose from the fact that `defined?` and `super` are both keywords and the possible issues with scoping in a dynamic method definition via a Proc. But I’m just guessing.

You should upgrade to Ruby 2.0 (or better yet 2.1) in order to fix this—or attempt to backport the patch yourself.